# Unable to restore ESRI reference in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have project which was developed on ASP.Net 4.5 and ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .Net 10.4. Now I have installed ArcGIS Runtime 10.4 and change framework from 4.5 to 4.6.1 and also tried to install nuget packages but still not able to restore references .I followed instruction mentioned in [ArcGIS SDK](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/guide/install-the-sdk.htm). How can I restore references? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't Runtime nuget packages it's complaining about, but ArcGIS Desktop assemblies (in fact the runtimes are listed right below and looks like they restored just fine).

Comment: What packages need to install to restore references